# Axis2 configuration files XML schemas or dtd files

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, apache-axis, dtd

Is there an XML schema or DTD files for axis2 configuration files, in particular axis2.xml and services.xml?

Its absence makes Eclipse unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  You should try looking at the [Axis2 Java web site](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)'s Subversion repository.

Comment: find them and get the tick

Comment: [source code ... site ... resources ... schemas](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/axis/axis2/java/core/trunk/src/site/resources/schemas/)

Comment: ok thanks, still Eclipse has problems with it. I hope someone will fix them some day.